# Harris Corner Detector yielding wrong points

Tags: c++

My harris corner detector isn't yielding the right corner points. I have followed the steps and I am wondering where it is failing.

I feel like I have followed the steps very clearly but it is not yielding correct results.

Here is a screenshot of the points that are detected.

[Harris detector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLzbB.png)

Code:

```
void MainWindow::HarrisCornerDetector(QImage image, double sigma, double thresh,
    CIntPt **cornerPts, int &numCornerPts, QImage &imageDisplay) {
    int r, c;
    int w = image.width();
    int h = image.height();
    double *bufferX = new double[w*h];
    double *bufferY = new double[w*h];
    double *bufferXY = new double[w*h];
    QRgb pixel;

    for (r = 0; r < h; r++)
        for (c = 0; c < w; c++)
    {
        pixel = image.pixel(c, r);
        bufferX[r*w + c] = (double)qGreen(pixel);
        bufferY[r*w + c] = (double)qGreen(pixel);
    }

    double *kernelX = new double[9];
    kernelX[0] = -1; kernelX[1] = 0; kernelX[2] = 1; 
    kernelX[3] = -2; kernelX[4] = 0; kernelX[5] = 2;
    kernelX[6] = -1; kernelX[7] = 0; kernelX[8] = 1;

    double *kernelY = new double[9];
    kernelY[0] = 1; kernelY[1] = 2; kernelY[2] = 1;
    kernelY[3] = 0; kernelY[4] = 0; kernelY[5] = 0;
    kernelY[6] = -1; kernelY[7] = -2; kernelY[8] = -1;

    Convolution(bufferX, w, h, kernelX, 3, 3);
    Convolution(bufferY, w, h, kernelY, 3, 3);

    for (r = 0; r<h; r++)
        for (c = 0; c < w; c++)
        {
            bufferXY[c + r*w] = bufferX[c + r*w] * bufferY[c + r*w];
            bufferX[c + r*w] = bufferX[c + r*w] * bufferX[c + r*w];
            bufferY[c + r*w] = bufferY[c + r*w] * bufferY[c + r*w];
        }

    //Computed image derivatives    


    double *kernelA = new double[9];
    kernelA[0] = 1; kernelA[1] = 1; kernelA[2] = 1;
    kernelA[3] = 1; kernelA[4] = 1; kernelA[5] = 1;
    kernelA[6] = 1; kernelA[7] = 1; kernelA[8] = 1;
    NormalizeKernel(kernelA, 3, 3);

    GaussianBlurImage(bufferX, w, h, sigma);
    GaussianBlurImage(bufferY, w, h, sigma);
    GaussianBlurImage(bufferXY, w, h, sigma);

    //Blurred each of the 3 images with the Gaussian

    double max = 0;
    double *Rmat = new double[w*h];
    for (r = 0; r<h; r++)
        for (c = 0; c<w; c++)
        {
            int index = c + r*w;
            double *harris = new double[4];
            harris[0] = bufferX[index];
            harris[1] = bufferXY[index];
            harris[2] = bufferXY[index];
            harris[3] = bufferY[index];

            double det = harris[0] * harris[3] - harris[1] * harris[2];
            double trace = harris[0] + harris[3];
            double R = det / trace;
            if (R > max)
                max = R;
            if (trace <= 0) R = 0;
            Rmat[index] = R;
        }

    //built matrix of harris corner value for each pixel    

    int radius = 10;
    numCornerPts = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r<h; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < w; c++)
        {
            double val = Rmat[c + r*w];
            if (val >= thresh) {
                int xRadius = min(min(radius, c), w - c - 1);
                int yRadius = min(min(radius, r), h - r - 1);
                assert(xRadius <= radius && yRadius <= radius);
                bool islocalmax = true;

                for (int xx = c - xRadius; xx <= c + xRadius; xx++) {
                    for (int yy = r - yRadius; yy <= r + yRadius; yy++) {
                        assert(xx >= 0 && xx < w && yy >= 0 && yy < h);
                        if (xx != c || yy != r) {
                            if (val <= 1.1*Rmat[xx + yy*w]) {
                                islocalmax = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (islocalmax)
                    numCornerPts++;
            }
        }

    *cornerPts = new CIntPt[numCornerPts];
    int p = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r<h; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < w; c++)
        {
            double val = Rmat[c + r*w];
            if (val >= thresh) {
                int xRadius = min(min(radius, c), w - c - 1);
                int yRadius = min(min(radius, r), h - r - 1);
                bool islocalmax = true;

                for (int xx = c - xRadius; xx <= c + xRadius; xx++) {
                    for (int yy = r - yRadius; yy <= r + yRadius; yy++) {
                        assert(xx >= 0 && xx < w && yy >= 0 && yy < h);
                        if (xx != c || yy != r) {
                            if (val <= 1.1*Rmat[xx + yy*w]) {
                                islocalmax = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (islocalmax) {
                    p++;
                    (*cornerPts)[p].m_X = c; (*cornerPts)[p].m_Y = r;
                }
            }
        }

    assert(numCornerPts == p);

    DrawCornerPoints(*cornerPts, numCornerPts, imageDisplay);
//  delete[] bufferX;

}

Helper methods:

void MainWindow::GaussianBlurImage(double *image, int w, int h, double sigma)
{
    // Add your code here
    int radius = (int)(ceil(sigma));

    int size = 2*radius + 1;
    double *kernel = new double [size*size];

    for (int x=0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < size; y++) {
            double v = pow((x - radius),2) + pow((y - radius),2); 
            double value = pow(e_, -v/(2.0*pow(sigma, 2)));
            kernel[y*size + x ] = value;
        }
    }

    // Make sure kernel sums to 1
    NormalizeKernel(kernel, size, size);
    Convolution(image, w, h, kernel, size, size);
}

// Convolve the image with the kernel
void Convolution(double *image, int w, int h, double *kernel, int kernelWidth, int kernelHeight)
{
    double* buffer = new double[w*h];
    for (int r = 0; r<h; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c<w; c++)
        {
            buffer[r*w + c] = image[r*w + c];
        }

    // For each pixel in the image...
    for(int r=0;r<h;r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < w; c++)
        {
            double value = 0;
            if ((c - kernelWidth/2 >= 0) && (c + kernelWidth/2 < w) && 
                (r - kernelHeight / 2 >= 0) && (r + kernelHeight< h)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < kernelWidth ; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < kernelHeight ; j++) {
                        int as = c + i - kernelWidth/2; int bs = r + j - kernelHeight/2;
                        value += buffer[bs*w + as] * kernel[i + j*kernelWidth];
                    }
                }
            }
            image[r*w + c] = max(0, min(255, (int) value )) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::vector` instead of manually dynamically allocating arrays. You have a bunch memory leaks throughout your code.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.. is there anything about the logic of the harris detector that is flawed? I computed the gradients X and Y using the 3 by 3 matrix of [-1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1] and v. v., computed X^2 and Y^2 and XY by squaring each entry and multiplying each of the X and Y, respectively,  and did a gaussian weighted sum on these three images. I used the three images to build a point by point harris matrix. But it is not correct. Is there anything in logic that is wrong?